# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I keep getting the console error code: **'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'**

Shown below is the full console error code:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jerry\OneDrive\Desktop\test\bot.mjs'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your terminal isn't in the right folder. Make sure you navigate to the right folder using `cd /folder`

Answer (score 0):

If you run the bot.mjs file from the terminal, be sure about you are in the right folder.

You can use the "ls" command to see if the file is really in there.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I had named my project file like included special symbol--> "&" so i changed this "and". issue solved. never use special symbols in project file name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33803794)